Uncaught Error: Could not find a matching route when redirecting to /login page after logout
I'm trying to implement JWT in my project and an article provides a nice solution:
https://dev.to/sanjayttg/jwt-authentication-in-react-with-react-router-1d03.
Routes.jsx
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../provider/authProvider";
import { ProtectedRoute } from "./ProtectedRoute";
import Login from "../pages/Login";
import Logout from "../pages/Logout";

const Routes = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();

  // Define public routes accessible to all users
  const routesForPublic = [
    {
      path: "/service",
      element: <div>Service Page</div>,
    },
    {
      path: "/about-us",
      element: <div>About Us</div>,
    },
  ];

  // Define routes accessible only to authenticated users
  const routesForAuthenticatedOnly = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <ProtectedRoute />, // Wrap the component in ProtectedRoute
      children: [
        {
          path: "",
          element: <div>User Home Page</div>,
        },
        {
          path: "/profile",
          element: <div>User Profile</div>,
        },
        {
          path: "/logout",
          element: <Logout/>,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  // Define routes accessible only to non-authenticated users
  const routesForNotAuthenticatedOnly = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <div>Home Page</div>,
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      element: <Login/>,
    },
  ];

  // Combine and conditionally include routes based on authentication status
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    ...routesForPublic,
    ...(!token ? routesForNotAuthenticatedOnly : []),
    ...routesForAuthenticatedOnly,
  ]);

  // Provide the router configuration using RouterProvider
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default Routes;

ProtectedRoute.jsx
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../provider/authProvider";

export const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();

  // Check if the user is authenticated
  if (!token) {
    // If not authenticated, redirect to the login page
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  // If authenticated, render the child routes
  return <Outlet />;
};

Github:
https://github.com/sanjay-arya/react-auth-demo
I basically created aa Auth context providing token information to all routes and allows access to routes on whether the user has a token or not. It also has a login and logout system removing/creating tokens.
The code provided works fine as it is. The problem arises when I want to redirect the user to the "/login" page instead of the "/" page after logging out. e.g. I changed navigate("/", { replace: true }) to navigate("/login", { replace: true }); in Logout.jsx.
I get this error:
react-router-dom.js?v=7652cf65:202 Uncaught Error: Could not find a matching route for errors on route IDs: 2
    at invariant (react-router-dom.js?v=7652cf65:202:11)
    at _renderMatches (react-router-dom.js?v=7652cf65:3167:33)
    at useRoutesImpl (react-router-dom.js?v=7652cf65:3033:25)
    at DataRoutes (react-router-dom.js?v=7652cf65:3422:10)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom_client.js?v=7652cf65:12171:26)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom_client.js?v=7652cf65:14577:28)
    at beginWork (react-dom_client.js?v=7652cf65:15912:22)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom_client.js?v=7652cf65:3674:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom_client.js?v=7652cf65:3699:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom_client.js?v=7652cf65:3733:39)
Show 19 more frames
console.js:213 The above error occurred in the <DataRoutes> component:

    at DataRoutes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=7652cf65:3419:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=7652cf65:3491:15)
    at RouterProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=7652cf65:3375:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/src/routes/index.jsx?t=1712483351401:26:7)
    at AuthProvider (http://localhost:5173/src/provider/authProvider.jsx:21:3)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

It's an uncaught error but even when adding errorElement to the routes the errors still persist. Even then, I still do not know why there would be an error. I've been trying to figure out the issue for hours but no success.

The general issue is that you are conditionally rendering your routes, so when the authentication condition based on the token changes, some routes you want to navigate to are not mounted and rendered yet. The solution is to unconditionally render the routes.
Update Routes to remove the token check and unconditionally render routesForNotAuthenticatedOnly routes and create a "protected route component" that does the inverse of ProtectedRoute to protect these routes from authenticated users.
Since there is a "protected" user home page and an "anonymous" home page both on the root "/" route, create a special component that checks the auth condition and conditionally renders either of the home pages in the public routes that are accessible by anyone at any time.
Example:
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../provider/authProvider";

export const AnonymousRoute = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();

  // Check if the user is authenticated
  if (!token) {
    // If not authenticated, render the child routes
    return <Outlet />;
  }

  // If authenticated, redirect to safe page
  return <Navigate to="/" />;
};

import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../provider/authProvider";
import { ProtectedRoute } from "./ProtectedRoute";
import { AnonymousRoute } from "./ProtectedRoute";
import Login from "../pages/Login";
import Logout from "../pages/Logout";

const HomePage = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();

  return token
    ? <div>User Home Page</div>
    : <div>Home Page</div>;
};

const Routes = () => {
  // Define public routes accessible to all users
  const routesForPublic = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <HomePage />,
    },  
    {
      path: "/service",
      element: <div>Service Page</div>,
    },
    {
      path: "/about-us",
      element: <div>About Us</div>,
    },
  ];

  // Define routes accessible only to authenticated users
  const routesForAuthenticatedOnly = [
    {
      element: <ProtectedRoute />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/profile",
          element: <div>User Profile</div>,
        },
        {
          path: "/logout",
          element: <Logout />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  // Define routes accessible only to non-authenticated users
  const routesForNotAuthenticatedOnly = [
    {
      element: <AnonymousRoute />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/login",
          element: <Login />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  // Combine and conditionally include routes based on authentication status
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    ...routesForPublic,
    ...routesForNotAuthenticatedOnly),
    ...routesForAuthenticatedOnly,
  ]);

  // Provide the router configuration using RouterProvider
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default Routes;


Thank you! But when you say "some routes you want to navigate to are not mounted and rendered yet", I originally thought that for const handleLogout = () => { setToken(); navigate("/", { replace: true }); };,  setToken() would first re-render the <Routes> component and mount the correct router i.e. The one that includes routesForNotAuthenticatedOnly before navigating. Why isn't the updated router rendered and mounted yet?

@byles1506 This is because React state updates are asynchronously processed while navigation actions are immediate. Think of any of the React setState functions as more of a "at your next earliest convenience React, please update this state to this value" and React places the update in a queue to be processed between render cycles. I hope this analogy makes sense.

@byles1506 The alternative is to place the navigate call in a setTimeout so it is placed at the end of the Javascript event queue and is called after all the enqueued React state updates are processed. This is a bit of a hack though and not recommended if using normal means like suggested in the answer works for you.
